# Why can beveling a Bezier curve solidify it?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

Why can you bevel a Bezier curve in blender?

Doesn't the word bevel mean making fillet or chamfer to an edge?
What is the inner logic behind curve beveling?

*I came from CAD program, in CAD beveling means give a hard edge a ramp or round, but here I saw solidifying a bezier curve, so I try to understand the inner logic, or at least the meaning of bevel in blender.*

Thanks !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a discussion topic about development decisions, and this is more related for https://devtalk.blender.org/ site

Comment: Thank you. But I just try to understand blender a little bit deeper, I don’t say beveling a curve has error in logic, or try to correct anything. I just don’t get it after long time thinking. Without knowing the answer, I could enjoy blender as well, only something has been bugging you whole year, you have to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beveling a curve creates a bevel: it allows you to change the profile that follows the curve. At a *Resolution* of 0, with the *Round* option, you will have 4 x 90° edges, so basically no bevel:

[image]

But if you increase the *Resolution* il will round the edges, which is a bevel, and if you choose the *Object* or *Profile* option it will give a custom bevel to the edges. It bevels the profile of the curve.

Comment: not sure why my answer was downvoted, it's always better to give an explanation  ;)  have I misudenrstood his question? I don't think so, it looks like he doesn't understand the meaning of bevel for curves

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much! I have been asking this questions long time, this is the best explanation I get so far.